# IE9 + background-image (PNG24) + background-repeat + background-position = BUG

Tags: css, internet-explorer, png, alpha

Suppose you got a code like this:

```
<div id="pattern"> </div>

#pattern {
 height: 400px;    
 background: #000 url(url_to_semitransparent_png); 
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-position: 100px 0;   
}
```

It behaves as expected in every browser, but IE. In IE it looks like repeating background overlaps with itself, while it should simply stick. This issue manifested itself while we were trying to animate `background-position`. You can see the code in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ya2AF/10/ (compare IE and Chrome to witness it). Be sure to uncomment `animate()` function to get it moving.

Has anyone encountered such behavior? Can we fight it?

Comment: I see animation in IE9 but not in Firefox 15.0.1 (on Windows 7 x64).

Comment: Firefox doesn't support background-position-x (I've updated fiddle). But that's not a point do you see it without visual artifacts in IE9?

Comment: OK, now I have something to compare the IE result to, and yes, I do see the artifact. No, I don't have a solution, sorry.